# How to trigger a lambda function using eventbridge schedule based on a cron expression and some additional criteria

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-event-bridge

I have created an infrastructure using Terraform to create a lambda function and trigger the lambda function based on the events from Eventbridge schedules.
For any cron expression, my infrastructure is working as expected. But, now I face a challenge to trigger the lambda function on the next Thursday of every month last Sunday.

My Eventbridge terraform script is below. I have made some changes so that the events are triggered on Thursdays falling in the date range of 24-31 and 1-4 to limit the event triggers and I am thinking to add the below logic:

1. The months of the previous and next Sunday to determine that the current Thur is either the last or the first Thu of the month.
2. To check if the date today is greater than the date of the last Sunday and if not then if the months are not the same for today's date and that of the date on Sunday.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "python_lambda_event_rule" {
  name        = "poc-rule"
  description = "Event rule for triggering the Python Lambda function"
        
  schedule_expression = "cron(0 0 26-31,1-4 * 4 *)" 
          
  # tags = var.tags
  tags = {
    name = "Event to trigger hello lambda",
    created_by = "Terraform",
    group = "POC"
  }
}
```

Can you please suggest the best way to get this done?

Comment: So are there any issues with the code you currently have?

Comment: When exactly do you want to trigger it? Are you saying on the Thursday following the last Sunday of a month?

Comment: If the expression is too complicated, I'll just let my code check it

Comment: @MichaelWiles Yes. Also, I don't care if the Thursday following the last Sunday of the month falls in the same month or in the next.

Comment: @Mink Yes I can do that in my lambda function. But, then my lambda will be triggered more times than I actually want it to. I am currently using this approach as a solution though and want to know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: It is not possible with a cron. What I'd suggest is have the cron just kick off every Thursday and then have the code check that it is a Thursday after the last Sunday.

Comment: @kanhaiyakumar just take it easy, I guess your Lambda function just need to run once a week, it costs nothing. In addition, you can use a time library to make sure you get what you need.

Comment: thank you, everyone, for your answers and suggestions. I have now scheduled it to run every week and I will have my code check for other contraints before running any business logic.